# Buster GUI Icons and text are too small

Tags: gui

I have a Pi4B-4 with a 13.3 diag HDMI screen. The fonts are too small even when preffed to "large". True of console text size too. Kindly, how do I resize them larger? Obvious noob question, (sight impaired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktop,
Right Click>> Desktop Preference>> Defaults
Then choose your setting and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The *Defaults* in *Appearance Settings* are suggestions only.
If you select the *System* tab you can select sizes for the *Font*.
The *Menu Bar* tab lets you  change the size up to 48*48 pixels.
Right-clicking on the *Panel* will also show settings.

Individual applications may have their own settings. E.g. *Vivaldi* browser has a *User Interface Zoom* option.

[Raspberry VI](http://www.raspberryvi.org/stories/index.html) has some help for visually impaired users.

`apt-cache search  magnifier` will show a couple of screen magnifier applications.

Ultimately there is a limit to how useful these are, because you run out of screen real estate. The only solution is a larger screen, I abandoned 13" screens in favour of a 21.5" monitor.